# NetworkX Force Layout Graph not displaying Properly with Mpld3 in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, networkx, mpld3

I am trying to display a NetworkX graph inside my Flask application, using matplotlib and the mpld3 library.

```
    f=plt.figure()
    pos=nx.spring_layout(G)

    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=nodes, node_color='r', node_size=50, alpha=0.8,with_labels=True)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,width=1.0,alpha=0.5)

    graph=mpld3.fig_to_html(f)
```

On my local machine, the graph looks fine, like this:

[image]

On Heroku, however, the graph is rendered like this:

[image]

With the exact same data and code in local and heroku, I am unable to figure out why the Heroku graph looks so different. What might be wrong?

Comment: I suspect this is not `mpld3` related; maybe you can use `matplotlib` to save as a .png and confirm this.

Comment: Is it possible that some configurations are different depending on whether you are on development or production?